# yii2 gridview: how to config css for filterModel

Tags: php, yii2

I want to config form text for 'filterModel'. Here's my code.

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
])
```

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: What do you mean by "config"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some options of GridzView for filterModel.
[GridView api](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html)

```
/**
 * @var array the HTML attributes for the filter row element.
 * @see \yii\helpers\Html::renderTagAttributes() for details on how attributes are being rendered.
 */
public $filterRowOptions = ['class' => 'filters'];
/**
 * @var array the options for rendering the filter error summary.
 * Please refer to [[Html::errorSummary()]] for more details about how to specify the options.
 * @see renderErrors()
 */
public $filterErrorSummaryOptions = ['class' => 'error-summary'];
/**
 * @var array the options for rendering every filter error message.
 * This is mainly used by [[Html::error()]] when rendering an error message next to every filter input field.
 */
public $filterErrorOptions = ['class' => 'help-block'];
```